# Storing data locally but with a similar data structure to Firestore (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a Flutter app using Firebase Firestore but now want to change it to store everything locally (due to cost, etc...)

I'm looking for a package that will let me do this without restructuring the data (i.e. not SQL). I have multiple collections and several levels of subcollections. So basically I'm looking for a way to store data locally but with a similar structure to Firestore.

Does anyone have recommendations for this? I want a package that is reliable and maintained (I don't want to use a package then find problems 6 months later because it's not being maintained)

Comment: you will find your need with this package [Isar](https://pub.dev/packages/isar)

Comment: So you aren't interested in a real-time feature for your database?